# how to break up time slots with specific interval for given time range

Tags: sql-server

I want to write sql query which will give out put as below
Query:

```
DivideTime('10','10:00:00','11:00:00')
```

OUTPUT:

10:10

10:20

10:30

10:40

10:50

11:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with a recursive common table expressions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_time_range] (@interval INT, @start_time TIME, @end_time TIME)
RETURNS @tbl TABLE ([time] TIME)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH [cte_recursion] AS
        (
            SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @interval, @start_time) [time]

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                DATEADD(MINUTE, @interval, [time]) [time]
            FROM [cte_recursion]
            WHERE   [time] < @end_time
        )
    INSERT INTO @tbl ([time])
    SELECT
        [time]
    FROM [cte_recursion]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); -- allows more than 100 iterations

    RETURN;
END
GO

SELECT
    *
FROM [dbo].[get_time_range](10, '10:00:00', '11:00:00');
```

Comment: Remeber to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` at the end as to avoid `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: Thanks @astander, I updated the answer to include that

Answer (score 1):

Using the `numbers` table:

```
select dateadd(minute, 10*n, @start_time)
from numbers n
where n <= datediff(minute, @start_time, @end_time)/@interval
```

http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/