# Getting 30 minute slots between time

Tags: sql-server, time, slot

I have a Start Datetime and a End Datetime.

```
Eg: 10:00 am - 12:00 pm
```

I have to create 4 slots between the, each ranging for 30 minutes.

```
Eg:  
10:00 am-10:30 am
10:30 am-11:00 am
11:00 am-11:30 am
11:30 am-12:00 pm
```

This 30 minutes can vary and is not a constant. I have tried a few things but they don't seem to work. Can someone please help. Thank you.

I have tried this but i only get the slot difference not the slotfrom-slotto

```
  SELECT 
   from_dt,to_dt,

   DATEDIFF(mi,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,from_dt ),0),to_dt )/60 as SlotNumber
FROM
   d
   group by  from_dt,to_dt, DATEDIFF(mi,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,from_dt ),0),to_dt )/60
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to break up time slots with specific interval for given time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938052/how-to-break-up-time-slots-with-specific-interval-for-given-time-range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks [@dwain.c](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/UserInfo999237.aspx) to get [Reference](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1358068-391-1.aspx)

```
--Declare table
DECLARE @t TABLE
(StartTime TIME, EndTime TIME)
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT '10:00', '12:00'
-- Make CTE
;WITH CTE (n) AS (
    SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartTime,EndTime)/30
    FROM @t) 30*(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1)
    FROM sys.all_columns
    )
-- QUERY
SELECT 
     TSStart=DATEADD(minute, n, StartTime)
    ,TSEnd=DATEADD(minute, n + 30, StartTime)
    ,Timeslot=CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, n, StartTime), 0) + ' - ' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), DATEADD(minute, n + 30, StartTime), 0)
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT n 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE n BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, DATEADD(minute, -30, EndTime))) a
ORDER BY TSStart
```

Comment: thank you so much @tinka.. Can you also explain me how i can book a slot and that does not appear in the available slots. ?

Comment: @FahadAshraf you should keep one boolean column `IsBooked` corresponding to Slots if value is `True` then record will not populate

Comment: but since this is at runtime. I am not saving the slots in the DB. only the booked slots. If i save the slots for everyday i would be saving many slots.

Comment: @FahadAshraf somewhere we have to track it, otherwise how we will bring the data

Comment: can we not save the from-to value in a different table and then exclude it from this query ? like by joining them or something ? Please help. I think we are almost there. :)

Comment: yes @FahadAshraf but don't delete it just set one FLAG so at least you can track it, if you want you can delete after day but i will not recommended :)